# how to define a type enum some string value, the others are any string?

Tags: typescript

##### I can get the vscode tip with `number`:

[image]

##### but when union with `string` failed:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The canonical way to do this is to intersect `string` with `{}`. `string` normally would absorb string literal types in a union (the string literal types are already part of `string` so in effect they are redundant for type checking)

```
type color = 'white' | 'black' | (string & {});
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAxg9gGzgJygXigcgO4AsCWwEmUAPlgEYICGMA1ieQBQDOwy+AdgOZQBkUAN4BfAJQBuKACgpCCMFgAGAFyxEKdFABEVWnS2z5sAIyr4SVBi3dqyEFqA)

Comment: I run to a new problem...
```

Answer (score -1):

The 'string' type not working as expected in typescript with union types. You should make it 'String' rather than 'string' and it will work I think.

```
type color = 'white' | 'black' | String;
```